# Android download file from url

Tags: android, get, android-download-manager

I am developing a simple web browser and faced with a problem. I use `DownloadManager` to download files from download requests. But I can't download files from `GET` requests like this: *`somewebsite.php?t=432513`*. When I'm trying to download file from such links using `DownloadManager` I got 1kb file of unknown format. Note, that I can download this file with Chrome or any other browser. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this 1 kb file is html with server error. You can open it as text/html file and see what's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are using Query parameter ##somewebsite.php?t=432513## , which return html page not the file. for downloading the file, the URL should have file in it.

Comment: html page is a file, not?